# How do I make this appear in Djanog-Python?

Tags: python, django

I'm currently in the process of building a hospital management app with using Django and Python

In the index page, I want to show the total patient numbers, yet the code I've inputted does not make that happen.

Also, I've cut most of the HTML code for this since the full code went over the word count limit.

[image: Dashboard]

The following are the code:

index.html

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Lifesaver</title>

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <!-- <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> -->
    <link href="{% static 'startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-gh-pages/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
    <!-- <link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link href="{% static 'startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-gh-pages/css/sb-admin-2.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
      

<body>

    <!-- Page Wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <!-- {% include 'lifesaver/sidebar.html' %} -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar">

            <!-- Sidebar - Brand -->
            <a class="sidebar-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" href="index.html">
                <div class="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15">
                    <i class="fas fa-laugh-wink"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3">LifeSaver </ul><div>
            </a>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider my-0">

            <!-- Nav Item - Dashboard -->
            {% include 'lifesaver/navbar_user.html' %}

        </ul>
        <!-- End of Sidebar -->

        <!-- Content Wrapper -->
        <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">

            <br>
        

            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div id="content">

                <!-- Begin Page Content -->
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <!-- Page Heading -->
                    <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
                        <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Dashboard</h1>
                        <a href="#" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-sm"><i
                                class="fas fa-download fa-sm text-white-50"></i> Generate Report</a>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Content Row -->
                    <div class="row">

                        **{% for patients in patients %}
                        <!-- Earnings (Monthly) Card Example -->
                        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
                            <div class="card border-left-primary shadow h-100 py-2">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                                        <div class="col mr-2">
                                            <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-primary text-uppercase mb-1">
                                                Patients</div>
                                            <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">{{total_patient.count}}</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-auto">
                                            **<i class="fas fa-calendar fa-2x text-gray-300"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}**

                        
</body>

</html>
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

#Work Related aka Department and Work Shift

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class WorkShift(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    start_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

#Personel Related aka Employees and Patients

class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    work_shift = models.OneToOneField(WorkShift, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Nurse(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    sector = models.ForeignKey(Department, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reports_to = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    work_shift = models.OneToOneField(WorkShift, default="", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    # in Nurse model
    def department_name(self):
        if self.sector_id:
            return self.sector.name
        else:
            return '' # or some other default

    def __str__(self):
         return self.name

class Patient(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Sick', 'Sick'),
        ('Healing', 'Healing'),
        ('Cured', 'Cured'),
        ('Deceased', 'Deceased'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, choices=STATUS)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, default="", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    care = models.ForeignKey(Nurse, default="", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Doctor, Nurse, Patient, Department, WorkShift
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import DoctorForm, NurseForm, PatientForm

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    patients = Patient.objects.all()
    nurses = Nurse.objects.all()
    doctors = Doctor.objects.all()
    department = Department.objects.all()

    total_patient = patients.count()
    sick = patients.filter(status='Sick').count()
    healing = patients.filter(status='Healing').count()
    cured = patients.filter(status='Cured').count()

    total_nurse = nurses.count()

    # if request.method == 'POST':
    #     form = 

    context = {
        'patients':patients, 'nurses':nurses,
        'doctors':doctors, 'total_patient ':total_patient,
        'sick':sick, 'healing':healing, 'cured':cured,
        'total_nurse':total_nurse,
        'department':department
    }

    return render(request, 'lifesaver/index.html', context)

#All Doctor Related

def doctor(request):

    doctors = Doctor.objects.all()

    context = {'doctors':doctors}
    return render(request, 'lifesaver/doctor.html', context)

def doctor_add(request):
    
    doctors = Doctor.objects.all()
    form = DoctorForm()

    context = {'doctors':doctors, 'form':form}

    return render(request, 'lifesaver/doctor_add.html', context)

def doctor_update(request):

    doctors = Doctor.objects.all(id=pk)
    form = DoctorForm(instance=doctors)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DoctorForm(request.POST, instance=doctors)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('Update completed')
            form.save()
            return redirect('doctor')
        else:
            print('Update not completed')
            print(form.errors)

    context = {'doctors':doctors, 'form':form}

    return render(request, 'lifesaver/doctor_update.html', context)

# Nurse Related

def nurse(request):
    nurses = Nurse.objects.all()
    workshift = WorkShift.objects.all()
    #department = Nurse.objects.get('sector')
    nurses_department = Nurse.objects.select_related('sector').all()

    context = {'nurses':nurses, 'workshift':workshift, 'nurses_department':nurses_department}
    return render(request, 'lifesaver/nurse.html', context)
    

def nurse_add(request):
    nurses = Nurse.objects.all()
    form = NurseForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NurseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Nurse Form is Valid")
            form.save()
        else:
            print("Nurse Form is Invalid")
            print(form.errors)
        return redirect('nurses')

    context = {'form':form,}
    return render(request, 'lifesaver/nurse_add.html', context)

def nurse_update(request):
    nurses = Nurse.objects.all(id=pk)
    form = NurseForm(instance=nurses)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NuseForm(request.POST, instance=nurses)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('Update completed')
            form.save()
            return redirect('nurse')
        else:
            print('Update not completed')
            print(form.errors)

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'lifesaver/nurse_update.html', context)

#All Patient Related

def patient(request):
    patients = Patient.objects.all()

    context = {'patients':patients}
    return render(request, 'lifesaver/patient.html', context)

def patient_add(request):

    patients = Patient.objects.all()
    form = PatientForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PatientForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Patient Form is Valid")
            form.save()
        else:
            print("Patient Form is Invalid")
            print(form.errors)
        return redirect('patient')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'lifesaver/patient_add.html', context)

def patient_update(request, pk):

    patients = Patient.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = PatientForm(instance=patients)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PatientForm(request.POST, instance=patients)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('Update completed')
            form.save()
            return redirect('patient')
        else:
            print('Update not completed')
            print(form.errors)
            
    context = {'form':form}

    return render(request, 'lifesaver/patient_update.html', context)

#Work Related

def department(request):
    departments = Department.objects.all()

    context = {'departments':department}
    return render(request, 'lifesaver/department.html', context)
```

What code should I input in order for the total patient count to display?

Answer (score 0):

Your naming is a bit confusing (so many 'patients')

'total_patient' in your views already counted, try removing .count from the template

In the for-loop in the template you call total_patient several times, it will just display the same number